# HTML background-attachment property not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, background

I created a fixed background page by using `background-attachment:fixed` in CSS. It is working fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE9, but in IE8 it is getting scrolled. Is there any filter used in IE8 for this fixed background property?

When I surfed I noticed that IE8 will take this fixed background when a doctype is defined, so I added this doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

But it is not having any effect in IE 8. Any idea about this issue?

Comment: Need the HTML and CSS to properly answer this. Try setting overflow: none; on the html and body element!

Comment: Try using HTML transitional: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`. Also have you set the background position explicitly?

Comment: Yup, we’ll need to see the CSS.

Comment: A doctype is never an afterthought and is required of all new web pages. It should be the very first thing typed in. New web pages have no need for the transitional one and should always use strict or the new HTML5 one.

Comment: This appears to be [a bug in how IE8 interprets `fixed`](http://www.standardista.com/css3/css3-background-properties/#bg1). You could work around it with a JavaScript hack, if you had to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `background-attachment` is on the `body` element, try adding:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Let me know and if not could you provide a link please?

Update

Try changing the position

```
background-position:left-top;
```